# IMAP - in_reply_to always blank

Tags: php, imap

I want to pair a reply with the original message.

I am connecting to a gmail account like so:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'somebody@gmail.com'
$password = 'password'; 

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
$max_emails = 3;

if($emails) {
  rsort($emails);

  foreach($emails as $email_number) {
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);             
    if($count++ >= $max_emails) break;                
  }
}
```

When an email in the inbox is a reply, the `[in_reply_to]` field appears within `imap_fetch_overview`, so it knows it's a reply, however this field is always blank.

How can I pair a reply to the sent message?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore this...

I was displaying results like so:

```
print_r($overview);
```

When doing this instead:

```
var_dump($overview);
```

The information is there.
Not sure why that is...